# Ember js transition and refresh when entered into the routed page

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-model

I am using ember model in my ember app and in the view I  perform some logic in the didInsertElement hook of the ember view -

```
// changing a field in the db via ajax and then 

this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('courses');
```

Now when I go to the courses route the field is not updated because ember model has not got the latest data from the api.

How do I make ember data to refresh the page after the transition.

Suggestions - 
1) Should I refresh after the ajax call
2) Should I refresh when I enter the courses route ?

Please help me out.

Comment: I'm not familiar w/ ember-data or ember-model but I'll do what I can to help debug your issue (assuming you are still working on this). Does the routes model method/hook get invoked when you transition from the above? If not ... are you doing a transition from a child route (nested) to a parent? If so you need to hack the route in ember 1.x (as it won't always fire). Here is a commit I use that shows the minimum to get this child/to parent "always" refresh the model behavior https://github.com/toranb/route-always-fires-model-hook-example/commit/e4c6dffa6609ba081aec99df49612d031d57f001

Comment: @ToranBillups Really appreciate your effort in answering this. But unfortunately I am not working on this anymore. Thanks again